# how to clear Kubuntu notifications

Tags: 12.04, kubuntu, kde, notification

Hi i have got KDE as my DE , everything is good . but i am getting problem with notifications that are appearing with bottom right corner .

I haven't found any way to clear them all with one-click , no option like clear all or so .

I got many notifications , so is there any way to clear all notifications at a time .

Thank you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be the "remove them all" pick

[image]